In Vivado Hardware manager, how can I (either by menu option or TCL script) read back the CRC from a programmed Xlinx/AMD 7-Series FPGA
With the old Xilinx ISE/iMPACT tools one could connect to an FPGA via JTAG, and then select a menu option to read out the CRC from the programmed part.  This was also useful from an engineering standpoint because we could put the CRC value on the drawings.  And the factory could then verify that the image they downloaded matched the CRC in the drawing (and not some other revision of the .bin file).
With the newer tools (Vivado) and AMD/Xilinx 7-Series FPGAs (like Aritx-7 or Spartan-7), I no longer see that option.
So, the question is, if I have a 7-series FPGA connected to the Vivado hardware manager via JTAG, how can I (either by menu option or TCL script) read back the CRC from the programmed FPGA.

For reading CRC try this, if the syntax matches your version.
# Open hardware and target device
open_hw
connect_hw_server
open_hw_target

# Get the first device (modify if you have multiple devices)
set device [lindex [get_hw_devices] 0]
refresh_hw_device $device

# Enable the CRC readback feature on the device
set_property BITSTREAM.CRC.ENABLE TRUE $device

# Retrieve the CRC value
set crc_value [get_property BITSTREAM.CRC.VALUE $device]

# Display the CRC value
puts "CRC Value: $crc_value"

